# nightwatch waitForElementVisible and assert.visible not working

Tags: json, node.js, nightwatch.js

am new to nightwatch

I just  copy the first code form http://nightwatchjs.org/ 
Below showing the code

```html
module.exports = {
  'Demo test Google' : function (client) {
    client
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .assert.title('Google')
      .assert.visible('input[type=text]')
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'rembrandt van rijn')
      .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
      .click('button[name=btnG]')
      .pause(1000)
      .assert.containsText('ol#rso li:first-child',
        'Rembrandt - Wikipedia')
      .end();
  }
};
```

And getting Failure

[error result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLVYD.jpg)

.waitForElementVisible('body', 20000) is showing error and also .assert.visible('input[type=text]') is getting fail

Comment: Do not post an image of your code

Comment: Could you please just paste your code here, it looks like you made some kind of mistake while pasting, code example would be helpful here

Comment: @timetraveler90 : shall you please check now. I mention the code above

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is that piece of code is a bit older, and google changed few things on their search page. So for testing purposes you could try it out with the following code:

```
module.exports = {
    'Demo test Google' : function (client) {
        client
            .url('http://www.google.com')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 5000)
            .assert.title('Google')
            .assert.visible('input[type=text]')
            .setValue('input[type=text]', ['rembrandt van rijn', client.Keys.ENTER])
            .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 5000)
            .click('button[name=btnG]')
            .pause(3000)
            .assert.containsText('#rso > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > h3 > a',
            'Rembrandt - Wikipedia')
            .end();
    }
};
```

It is edited and should work fine, test it and let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: No, now also getting previous error. [output](https://ibb.co/gDdg8G)   and     
 [folder structure](https://ibb.co/f7CDNb) , Is there any more configuration needed.

Comment: Share your nightwatch.json code, for any case, because i am not sure what breaks your code right now

Comment: here is the [nightwatch.jason](https://www.mediafire.com/file/9xsg94da6f15qf5/nightwatch.json)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line of code from

```
"start_process" : false
```

to

```
"start_process" : true
```

Comment: "start_process" : true "   
              it change the server execution method.  when I run the code  .setValue('input[name="q"]', 'nightwatch')  the "nightwatch" string not entering in text field.

Comment: Change that line of code to true, and use the test code from my second answer and let me know if it is working